# print pressed key in masked textbox

Tags: c#

How can I print in the text of a maskedtextbox the key that is being pressed while the maskedtextbox is selected?

```
    private void maskedTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Edit:

Solution:

Instead of using KeyPress I used KeyDown event.

```
    private void maskedTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        maskedTextBox1.Text = e.KeyCode.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Provide more info. Looking at the property of e.KeyChar may help  you.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the KeyChar property of KeyPressEventArgs. So, you could call something like:

```
Console.WriteLine(e.KeyChar);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This returns the key character I need the keycode so that if I press "Supr" It shows the keycode of Supr.

Answer (score 0):

Maskedtextbox.text = e.keychar